# How to fix file-system error causing read only mode?

Tags: 18.04, filesystem, fsck, read-only

Whenever I download any package or anything and in between that process if anything went wrong, my ubuntu goes into read-only mode and always I have to do `sudo fsck -fy` to fix that and every time reboot after that.

It's very irritating to reboot every time for such an error. 
Is there any other way to fix that or any suggestion to restrict my ubuntu to go into a read-only mode?

**Note**: *I don't have the kernel knowledge. I am just using ubuntu 18.04 for programming for the last 1 year.*

Comment: If you have problems like that there will be a cause. Have you looked for it?   I'd start with your hardware (cap-check, SMART to check hdd/ssd, ram test) then move to your setup (anything unusual added to your base system, are API/ABI clashes because of things you've added intended for other systems/releases etc that would cause data to become corrupted? etc)

Comment: Hi @guiverc 
Yes, I tried to look on to the cause, sometimes I found that some packages have unmet dependencies which caused that and after that, I am unable to run any write command, like to force install that unmet dependencies, as the system is in read-only mode.
And sometimes unable to find the cause, Can you please let me know how can I check that I mean any process to check that and fix??

Comment: Unmet dependencies relate to 3rd party packages/sources you've added no doubt, and should never be force installed. If you've force installed packages that have created this condition, I'd suggest a re-install as your it'll mean your system is unstable and untrustworthy though as stated I doubt that's the reason for your *fs* being flipped RO.  Reading logs is the best bet (reason given was?) but it's usually hardware in my experience (my last comment) or imperfect power filter, & I'd switch to using a 'live' (w/w-out persistence) system that's easily re-created until hardware is proven.

Comment: Thanks a lot @guiverc
Now I will check the logs from next time and try to figure out, what's probably is making my file system corrupt.
As the problem is fixed as of now by using ```sudo fsck -fy```, Still can I check now what's may be the error if that is in hardware or anything else, or can be checked only when that error occurs??

Comment: What logs you have will depend on your hardware, if it's a enterprise grade server it'll provide clues as to outside of threshold power events, temperature high/lows etc, however consumer grade devices have none of that. My own systemd journal goes back to 28-feb-2020, and I had a very quick scan for events like yours, but didn't find any. You'll likely have dated detail I don't have so may find it in yours (and have an event in your logs, I've had it occur twice since 2017 install but can't recall when but very unlikely in 28-feb-2020 to now period)

Comment: @guiverc I tried to run the SMART test, and it's giving SELF-TEST FAILED, so how can I check what's going wrong??

Comment: Any data on that drive should be got off immediately (starting with the most important, down to least important and replacement sought). SMART is most useful in its stats, they give the best clue as to health of drive (esp. if monitored & as you notice changes in its reports)..https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools

Comment: @guiverc Hey, I tried a lot to find the issue, I got to know that it's happening due to hdd bad sectors only (as you said earlier). Here is my important error logs (https://pastebin.com/rPrj1gks) , Can you please help me?
I am stucked.

Comment: Personally I just write data off on a bad disk & rely on my backups. The more time you spent trying to 'fix' (eg. `fsck`) issues, you slightly lower the chance you have of getting data off in my experience.  Yes you can use `testdisk`, `photorec` etc (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery) but they are slow..

Comment: Hi @guiverc, Thanks a lot for your reply, How can I write data off on a bad disk ??
Please provide me some resources?

Comment: The link I provided already included detail on `ddrescue` & like tools (inc. important detail such as not writing to your drive; `fsck` being a no-no as it writes to fix issues & makes bad disks worse).  By *write off* I meant I usually opt to ignore the dead drive (I keep it should I actually discover my backup strategy is flawed, but just restore backups as recovery tools are very very very slow).   Start with the already provided DataRecovery link.  *Note: the file system & other details I don't know may also influence my actions, adjust for your situation as appropriate*